# How to get type from its string representation

Tags: typescript

How to to make typescript derive generic argument of `assertTypof` based on value of `expectedType`

Namely, I want to apply function below without specifying `number` two times

[playable example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20TypeLiteral%20%3D%20%22string%22%20%7C%20%22number%22%20%7C%20%22boolean%22%20%7C%20%22symbol%22%20%7C%20%22undefined%22%20%7C%20%22object%22%20%7C%20%22function%22%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20I%20know%20its%20bad%20to%20return%20generic%2C%20but%20dont%20know%20how%20to%20make%20without%20it%0D%0Afunction%20assertTypeof%3CT%3E(expectedType%3A%20TypeLiteral%2C%20target%3A%20any)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20actualType%20%3D%20typeof%20target%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(actualType%20%3D%3D%3D%20expectedType)%20return%20target%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20throw%20new%20Error(%60Expected%20%24%7BexpectedType%7D%2C%20but%20got%20%24%7BactualType%7D%60)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20n1%20%3D%20assertTypeof%3Cnumber%3E('number'%2C%201)%0D%0Aconst%20n2%20%3D%20assertTypeof%3Cnumber%3E('number'%2C%20%7B%7D))

```
type TypeLiteral = "string" | "number" | "boolean" | "symbol" | "undefined" | "object" | "function"

// I know its bad to return generic, but dont know how to make without it
function assertTypeof<T>(expectedType: TypeLiteral, target: any): T {
    const actualType = typeof target
    if (actualType === expectedType) return target

    throw new Error(`Expected ${expectedType}, but got ${actualType}`)
}


const n1 = assertTypeof<number>('number', 1) // fine
const n2 = assertTypeof<number>('number', {}) // error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can encode string -> type mapping in an interface, and use [indexed access type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types) as return type for `assertTypeof`:

```
interface TypeMap {
    string: string,
    number: number,
    boolean: boolean,
    symbol: Symbol,
    undefined: undefined,
    object: object,
    function: Function
};

function assertTypeof<N extends keyof TypeMap>(expectedType: N, target: any)
 : TypeMap[N] {
    const actualType = typeof target
    if (actualType === expectedType) return target

    throw new Error(`Expected ${expectedType}, but got ${actualType}`)
}

const n1 = assertTypeof('number', 1) // fine
const n2 = assertTypeof('number', {}) // runtime error
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but you're not using mapped types (which can be recognized by the use of the `in` keyword in the index signature, as in `{ [K in keyof T]: string }`); you're using the [indexed access operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types).

Comment: implemented your idea here https://github.com/BjornMelgaard/ramda-asserters/blob/master/src/assertTypeof.ts