# How do I get a TypeScript type name from string?

Tags: typescript

So I have a type map of format `{ 'type': type }` and want to use it in a generic function to "dynamically" determine the return type, but well it doesn't work.

Here's the code:

```js
// Using type instead of interface. I believe it doesn't make any difference?
type SupportedPropertyTypes = {
  string: string,
  number: number,
  boolean: boolean,
  object: any
}

type PropertyType = keyof SupportedPropertyTypes

type PropertyDefinition<T extends PropertyType, N = false> = {
  type: T,
  nullable?: N,
  fallback?: PropertyValue<T,N> | (() => PropertyValue<T,N>)
}

type StorageConfig = {
  namespace: string,
  properties: {
    [key: string]: PropertyDefinition<PropertyType>
  }
}

type PropertyValue<T extends PropertyType, N = false> = SupportedPropertyTypes[T]
  | (() => SupportedPropertyTypes[T])
  | (N extends true ? null : never)

const config = {
  namespace: 'foo',
  properties: {
    foo: { type: 'string' },
    bar: { type: 'number', fallback: 1338 },
    baz: { type: 'boolean', nullable: true },
    complicatedThing: {
      type: 'object',
      nullable: true,
      fallback: () => ({
        foo: 'bar',
        bar: 'baz',
        arr: [1,2],
      })
    }
  }
}

function getFallback<TProps extends StorageConfig['properties'], T extends keyof TProps> (key: T, props: TProps) {
  return typeof props[key].fallback == 'function'
    ? props[key].fallback()
    : props[key].fallback
}

// Expected: const foo: { foo: string, bar: string, arr: number[] }
// Got: error
const foo = getFallback('complicatedThing', config.properties)
```

And here goes the error:

```
Argument of type '{ foo: { type: string; }; bar: { type: string; fallback: number; }; baz: { type: string; nullable: boolean; }; complicatedThing: { type: string; nullable: boolean; fallback: () => { foo: string; bar: string; arr: number[]; }; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [key: string]: PropertyDefinition<keyof SupportedPropertyTypes, false>; }'.
  Property 'foo' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type '{ type: string; }' is not assignable to type 'PropertyDefinition<keyof SupportedPropertyTypes, false>'.
      Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof SupportedPropertyTypes'.(2345)
```

Wrote this code based on solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57254884/generate-typescript-type-from-string-value) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46247277/how-to-get-type-from-its-string-representation) but I'm probably still missing something.

Comment: Hmm, there's a lot of stuff going on in that code, but as far as I can see, `getFallback()` doesn't need to care about it, and you could write it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wR0Rvm).  Note that your implementation doesn't *call* the fallback method, so you should be expecting `foo` to be a function and not a value the function returns.  If that's wrong you should [edit] the code to be a proper [mre].  Anyway, does this address the question sufficiently? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: > Note that your implementation doesn't call the fallback method

Updated the snippet, thanks.

Comment: So then [this version](https://tsplay.dev/NB8kpW) would handle the different possible return types... again, without caring much about the types at the top.  Does that work for you?  If not, what specifically is wrong with it?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but your solution implies that `fallback` always exists which is not the case (see the `PropertyDefinition` type in my code snippet - `fallback` is optional). If you pass `foo` instead of `complicatedThing` it won't work. See [here](https://tsplay.dev/mA8yRN). The problem is we never know whether `fallback` is there or not - if there's no fallback, I just want `undefined`.

Comment: So we can make `fallback` optional as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/m3ByjN) then?  Would that work now?